# Azure ad b2c sign in flow with google identity provider

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have this issue for two days now,

I have a web app that uses azure ad b2c for authentication only, and it use redirect, the problem is when login with identity provider with a user created with the bellow payload, i get user not found (because the issuerAssignedId should come from google but how ??).

I tried changing the name of the key to signInNames so I don't have to set the issueId but it gives me 404, while user creation with b2c

```
const b2c_user = {
      accountEnabled: user.is_active,
      displayName: user.username,
      mail: user.email,
      mailNickname: user.username,

      identities: [
        {
          signInType: "userName",
          issuer: "stg.onmicrosoft.com",
          issuerAssignedId: user.username,
        },
        {
          signInType: "emailAddress",
          issuer: "stg.onmicrosoft.com",
          issuerAssignedId: user.email,
        },
        {
          signInType: "federated",
          issuer: "Google-OAUTH",
          issuerAssignedId: user.email,
        },
      ],

      userPrincipalName: `${user.username}@stg.onmicrosoft.com`,
      passwordProfile: {
        forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: false,
        password: user.password,
      },
};
```

Comment: Third party providers and users can hide their username or not share it with your B2C, in Apple case they can even hide the email address. You only can deal with user.email, rest of information can be shared with your B2C or not  depending of user preferences. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a federated user like this because you don't have the ID.

The identity array in B2C looks like e.g.:

```
"identities": [
  {
    "signInType": "userName",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "emailAddress",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "federated",
    "issuer": "facebook.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
  }
]
```

When you login to Google, B2C creates a "shadow" account for the user and assigns the issuerAssignedId that it gets from Google.

In this scenario, B2C creates two **separate** accounts.

To link the two accounts, refer to [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#account-linking).

Comment: How is that possible for azure b2c to recognize another local account is associated with this shadow account, can you please give more details?